Is brightness for WS2812B LED voltage dependent?
I understand that this would be true for any other regular LED.
The doc states that it accepts +3.5~+5.3 V.
I was wondering if it is somehow internally converted to operate at the same level as long as power supply is in the nominal range. Will 0xAA0000 for 3.5V give out the same brightness as 0xAA0000 for 5V

I'm not sure if it is too optimistic to assume that the chip designers are aware of the importance of driving the LEDs with constant current.
Anyway. From the datasheet:

It mentions a programmable constant-current control (don't understand the 12V part, though. Maybe a typo?) to ensure consistent brightness.

I guess the only way to know is probably to test it.
